# Remove maven suggestion from Eclipse quickfix menu

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

How can I remove the M2 suggestion from the quickfix menu? I constantly add maven dependencies to my pom.xml by mistake when I want to use the CTRL+1 feature.

I tried to reduce the Content Assist options for the Java Editor but I was unable to remove it.

I'm using Eclipse Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain why you would like to have these m2 proposals removed and not moved to the bottom, for example? See [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Reordering would also be an option. The option just caused so many issues that I just wanted to get rid of it. Moving it down would also help.

Answer (score 1):

In the **preferences *Maven > User Interface*** disable the option ***Suggest adding Workspace Projects as dependencies on missing types*** for that.

For details about this option and its implementation see [Eclipse m2e pull request #1409 *Add a preference to configure the relevance and search for workspace*](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/pull/1409).