# Customize Eclipse Quickfix Popup

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-lsp4mp

When I press CTRL+1 the quickfix popup opens but since some of the recent releases the menu has changes. Now additional actions are on top like Generate OpenAPI or Add maven dependencies. This is driving me mad because I just want to add the variable in-place and not check the menu. Is there a way to get rid of any non-java editor related operations?

[image: Quickfix Window Popup]

I'm on:

Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
Build id: 20231201-2043

Comment: I doubt the _Generate OpenAPI Annotations_ is an Eclipse built-in quick fix, but a quick fix contributed by a plugin you have installed. The _Add Maven dependencies_ quick fixes can be turned off in the preferences: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77510150/6505250

Comment: You are right. I think it originates from lsp4mp.

Comment: The code of the lsp4mp _Generate OpenAPI Annotations_ quick fix is [here](https://github.com/eclipse/lsp4mp/blob/302b7a12737de3180eb6d0cf009e8c6a7323ad99/microprofile.jdt/org.eclipse.lsp4mp.jdt.core/plugin.xml#L234-L238) and [here](https://github.com/eclipse/lsp4mp/blob/302b7a12737de3180eb6d0cf009e8c6a7323ad99/microprofile.jdt/org.eclipse.lsp4mp.jdt.core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/lsp4mp/jdt/internal/openapi/java/MicroProfileGenerateOpenAPIOperation.java#L51). The quick fix seems to be always shown for this type of Java project. If you want to change this, consider to contribute to lsp4mp.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I might do that - although my knowledge of the Eclipse API is limited (Only worked on a custom plugin about 15 years ago)